# How to Check Table Exist or not in Suger ORM Android

Tags: android, orm, android-sqlite, sugarorm

I am working on Android Application and i am using Suger ORM for my database operation. Now i have scenario where i have to check if "SomeTable" don't exist then create it and Insert the record and if table already exist and having some record i have to update the records.
I have write this code to check if table don't exist then create the record and save it.

```
Total_Budget_List = Total_Budget.listAll(Total_Budget.class);
if (Total_Budget_List.size() == 0)
{
    for (int i=0;i<Total_Budget_List.size();i++)
    {
        totalbudget = new Total_Budget(Select_Members.get(i).getId()+"",CurrentDate,per_person_budget+"");
        totalbudget.save();
    }
}
```

But i am getting no such table exist in the database. 
Now how can i check that if table exist and is there any record in that table.

Comment: user1722376 Hi, You got any update on this.

Answer (score 4):

Surround your code with try / catch block. You can handle SQLiteException if your table not exists.